# Return an Array of Abbreviated Strings with .filter() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, filter, substring

If I have an array of strings that I would like to abbreviate with the filter() method.

How would I use filter() in combination with str.substring (or another string method if applicable)?

In the following code I would like to return the first four characters of each name, but it doesn't seem to be working.

JavaScript

```
let poshNames = ["Markol", "Andile", "Jazzmine", "Famisynth"];
let nickNames;

nickNames = poshNames.filter(function(name){

  return name.str.substring(0,4);

});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` is your friend: `poshNames.map(x => x.substring(0, 4))`

Comment: Because that is not what filter() does. When in doubt ... *read the manual!* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter Basic research is expected before asking questions

Comment: **[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?s=1|80.5431)**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @charlietfl It's for a college project and I have to get the first four letters using the .filter() method.  I thought substring would do this.  The MDN docs are almost impossible for newbies to programming to make head or tail of, and are written for people who have years of programming experience, who have a deep understanding of the language, and need a reference point for when they've forgotten stuff or new stuff is added to the language.

Comment: That is absolutely ridiculous. You just aren't reading them thoroughly. There are lots of other resources on web also for learning about methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)
 and it will work:

```
let poshNames = ["Markol", "Andile", "Jazzmine", "Famisynth"];
let nickNames;

nickNames = poshNames.map(function(name) {
  return name.substring(0,4);
});
```

What `filter` does is essentially return an array that contains every element in the array for which the function returns `true`.

What `map` does, on the other hand, is return an array that contains the value the function returns for every value in the array.

**Note:** Both methods return a new array without affecting the original.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const poshNames = ["Markol", "Andile", "Jazzmine", "Famisynth", "H"];
const nickNames = poshNames.map(name => name.substring(0,4));

console.log(nickNames);
```

Comment: The resource you have linked is about the `Map` constructor, not `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: You're welcome @GrégoryBourgin. And you gave a solid answer by the way. You've earned an upvote from me!